# Taking in a filepath and returning a list of dictionaries that correspond to data in a .json file

Tags: python, json

input(s) to this function:
filepath: a string representation of the full path to a json file

This function will be taking in a filepath and returning a list of dictionaries that correspond to the tweet data that was in the .json file.

Take note here that the key of the dictionaries in the original JSON files is the tweet_id, which becomes a new field in the output JSON.

Above are the directions for a function that I am looking to create.

I am given 
def read_json_file(filepath)

Any suggestions on what to do would be much appreciated as I am struggling where to get started.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without a reproducible example sorry. Descriptions of code are not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the python JSON module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

It should be as simple as reading the file into `json.load()`. Try something like:

```
import json
filename = "my_file.json"
with open(filename, 'r') as my_file:
    x = json.load(my_file)
```

Comment: Looks great, exactly what OP needs. And +1 for documentation link.